# How To Put Container Over Extended Divs?

Tags: html, css

This is best to describe in pictures! The box with the asldskd, i want to be where the red area is. I want to put a logo in the black area and then put seperate content into the green area. I basically want to have the black and green extensions, but i want the content to be inside a 900px container.

this is what i have now. i tried using z-index to do this. is there a way to force the black green bars outside the 900px container, or do i need to keep the container below it?

```
<div id="header"> laksjdf</div>
<div id="subheader"> alskdjf</div>

<div id="container">
asdf
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
#header {
width:100%;
height:70px;
background-color:black;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
 }

#subheader {
width:100%;
height:25px;
background-color:green;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
 } 

#container {
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid black;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, I made a codepen for you, tell me if it whats you wanted

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yHzxd

Comment: thats interesting how you organized it.. i didnt even think of it that way. very cool.

Comment: i was thinking you only used the container ONCE.. didnt think of multiple times.. duh.. thanks again

Comment: It all depends on your design haha :)